# Java Jackson - XML to POJO

Tags: java, xml, jackson, pojo

I have used Jackson before to convert JSON to POJO and that works fine, now I am trying to do it with XML and I have having difficulties.

I have the following code:

```
ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
GoodreadsResponse response = xmlMapper.readValue("<GoodreadsResponse><Request><authentication>true</authentication></Request><book><id>6465707</id></book></GoodreadsResponse>", GoodreadsResponse.class);
System.out.println(response);
```

GoodreadsResponse.java

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "GoodreadsResponse")
public class GoodreadsResponse {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "book")
    private Book book;

    public Book getBook() { return book; }
}
```

Book.java

```
public class Book {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id")
    private String id;

    public String getId() { return id; }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/stax2/ri/Stax2ReaderAdapter
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.deser.XmlTokenStream.<init>(XmlTokenStream.java:1
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.deser.XmlTokenStream.<init>(XmlTokenStream.java:108)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.deser.FromXmlParser.<init>(FromXmlParser.java:171)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser(XmlFactory.java:546)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory.createParser(XmlFactory.java:418)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2146)
```

Whatever I do I cannot get it working, I am not sure if my classes are correct or not.

Can someone have a look and see if they can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Define not working, what is your output? It's throwing an exception?

Comment: So it can't find the org/codehaus/stax2/ri/Stax2ReaderAdapter class on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I added strax2-api and jackson-module-jaxb-annotations libraries and it's working now :)

Comment: You mean `stax2-api`?